# How to solve BSTR leak memory com object?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

at first excuse for my bad English .

i am  using Microsoft  ISA  Server  2006 c++ programming SDK .

i get the information  from Isa server by isa functions that needs  BSTR variable  , but it make  memory leak and  by using `::sysFreeString(BSTR)` it doesn't solve the memory leak . 
what should i have to do ?

```
FPCLib::IFPCLogEntryPtr::get_ClientIP(BSTR *);
```

Comment: suggest you post (cutdown) code

Comment: did you allocate it with SysAllocString?

Comment: @sam: You should be posting your code for us to help you out but anyways, have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xda6xzx7(v=vs.71).aspx, Hth :)

Answer (score 1):

By default, COM `BSTR` values are cached by the runtime library, which can give the appearance of a leak over time.  Even though your own code has no leaks, the heap size still grows - very annoying.

If you want to rule this out as a cause, you can disable using the [SetOaNoCache API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644360.aspx).

If you still have an apparent leak after doing that, you can track it down using [Process Dumper](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E089CA41-6A87-40C8-BF69-28AC08570B7E) to get consecutive snapshots and then run it again to compare them.  Run this against your Debug build if possible, as the callstacks are easier to decipher in that case.